# Export a pdf and open it in email attachment

Tags: excel, vba, string, pdf, attachment

I'm new to this, so every line of code here is put together with bits and pieces I picked up from here and there by myself and what i have learned from it.

So what what I'm trying to do is attach the pdf created in this code, but when I add the string (T) in .Attachments.Add it wont open the email app if I remove the (T) it opens the email, so i cant see what i am doing wrong here....

```
Sub Transpose()

 Dim Data_Array
 Dim OutPut_Array()
 Dim LR As Long, Counter As Long, LR2 As Long
 Dim i As Long
 
 

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  'Find the last row of your data in Sheet3 Column A
  'I added 1 so that the conditional statement below
  'doesn't exclude the last row of data
  With Sheets(1)
     LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row + 1
     Data_Array = .Range("K3:K18" & LR).Value2
  End With

    'See explanation in the edit section below
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = LBound(Data_Array, 1) To UBound(Data_Array, 1)

        'if the cell is not blank then increase the counter by one
        'and for each non blank cell in the Data_Array,
        'add it to the OutPut_Array
        'If its not blank then output the prepopulated OutPut_Array to Sheet4 and
        'set the counter back to zero
        If Trim(Data_Array(i, 1)) <> vbNullString Then
            Counter = Counter + 1

            ReDim Preserve OutPut_Array(1 To 1, 1 To Counter)

            OutPut_Array(1, Counter) = Data_Array(i, 1)

        Else

            With Sheets(2)
                LR2 = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                .Range("B" & LR2 + 1).Resize(1, Counter).Value2 = OutPut_Array
            End With

            Counter = 0
        End If
             
        
    Next i
    
    'Worksheets("SQ-AP-I-S360_Esp totais Reg Da").Activate
    'Sheet(1).Activate
    
' With Sheets(1)
    
  '  ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
  '  "C:\Users\danie\Desktop\test ub\Espessuras de Under Body " & Range("E5").Value & Format(Now(), " dd-mm-yy"), _
  '  Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
  '  IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
     
'End With


  
  'Save PDF VERSION
  



     'send_attachment()

Dim OApp As Object, OMail As Object, signature As String

Dim T As String
 
 T = "C:\Users\danie\Desktop\test ub\Espessuras de Under Body " & Range("E5").Value & Format(Date, " dd-mm-yy")
    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    T, Quality:= _
    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True

Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)

With OMail
    
End With

signature = OMail.body

With OMail
   ' .To = ""
    .Subject = "Espessuras de Under Body " & Range("E5") & Format(Date, " dd-mm-yy")
    .Attachments.Add T
    '.body = ""
    '.Send
    .Display
End With

Set OMail = Nothing
Set OApp = Nothing


'ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `On Error Resume Next` silently swallows any errors...  Also FYI your filename has no ".pdf" extension.

Comment: `Data_Array = .Range("K3:K18" & LR).Value2` should probably be `Data_Array = .Range("K3:K" & LR).Value2`

Comment: @TimWilliams, thank you very much Tim that solved it is running as it should now.